# Regex to get domains (incl. top level) from list of URLs

Tags: regex, bash, grep, sublimetext2

I have a list of URLs, some of which include subdirectories, query parameters etc. Others are incomplete and stop abruptly with a space sign or line break (e.g., http://www.google).

I want to use a regex in grep to match only the domains (including the protocol and top level domain) of these URLs, e.g., http://www.google.com, http://www.amazon.com etc.

I used Sublime Text 2 and came up with the following regex which seems to do the job:

```
https?://[^/\n ]*
```

Using this in grep in the following way, however, fails:

```
grep -E "https?://[^/\n ]*"
```

In the results, URLs are matched including subdirectories, query-paths etc.

What is the difference between regular expressions in grep as for example in Sublime Text causing this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file as well

Comment: `grep` displays any line (the whole line) containing the regex, not just the matching text. I do not know anything about `Sublime Text 2`.

Comment: @jdamian that was the reason it didn't work! I changed the behavior using the -o parameter and now it works as desired. I added a corresponding answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jdamian pointed out the answer in a comment under the question. Grep was selecting the whole line (including undesired subdirectories and queries). Using the -o parameter, everything worked as expected. The complete command I needed was thus:

```
grep -Eo "https?://[^/\n ]*"
```